# iterate in a global variable enriched by a callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I retrieve data from a webservice via a javascript Class with a Get method with a Callback.

On the callback, I'm pushing data into a global variable to use it later.

When I want to use the global variable, I get to see the items that are in it by a console.log (), but cannot iterate the variable to retrieve each item to display them.

the data_service variable is of typeOf object

The getInfoService () method is called on an onClick ().

```
const data_service = [];

function getInfoService (url){

    var ws= new WS_api(true, "application/json");
    var ws_services_url = url;
  
    // load and build services from webservices
    ws.get(ws_services_url, getInfoServices_callback);
    
    // I see elements in data_servcie variable
    console.log(data_service);
    
    // i can't iterate in data_service variable
    data_service.forEach(function (version) {
        console.log(version)
    })

}

function getInfoServices_callback(content) {

    // Array of all information
    data = JSON.parse(content);
   
    data.forEach(function (version) {
        
        if (version.software_item_type == "service") {
            //console.log(version);
            
            data_service[version.version] = 
            {
              name: version.id,
              version: version.version,
              status: version.status,
              iteration: version.iteration_id
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The console.log of data_service
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not iterate an object by using the array.filter() method because it is an object, not an array to iterate an object you should use Object.keys() method.
Here's what you may be looking for.

```
Object.keys(data).forEach(version => {
    console.log(version)
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work.
It is as if, the variable was visible but impossible to use the content

Comment: I just edit my answer. forEach function is not for Object. to iterate an object you should use Object.keys() function